# Create a 256 byte RSA encrypted block from a public key

Tags: java, php, rsa

Hello I am trying to write a php function/class that will connect to a remote (java) server and send a message to it that has been encoded with a 256 byte RSA block using a public key.

The github of the java server is here : https://github.com/vexsoftware/votifier

(search for: Protocol Documentation).

This is how i have to send the data. Now my problem is that:

a) the public key is a continuous string.

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsdG2qEpV74TQOwJEXU6BCBoXTLPXEG/Q5P3pkhpn433bStahMbqHROda7QgInfqMHvkAoFm84mNzckH+YsBRIiCRw3c7vYArWfGmmqIdr/NiLdS/pmNm2PnPDRpk/VadCwcOlSoCP6/RjUncMKqv0LW89DtCum5MrptDCkSrAgRP5ZOAHoBJehk6YW2jfpD2CfBpQsu9v7UNLkZ3ZnNxWNCKnkxiB6mqA7aDFh9J4XA+9amBC5oj/ZVfwHNiXq3IB4tMdgZsx/+DesS2mZ0ML78fCKXSOfT4xbfSlGGIyI7QsfqzB4Fh8d9WUuxADeFznTVfy185pGinOpbjDuH8+wIDAQAB
```

and every function i found on the net doesnt do what i need.

b) The server responds either with a default message if you send the wrong data or (i am guessing here) an OK message when all is good.

Does anyone know how to make this RSA block ? I mean it has to be 256 bytes and i got no clue how to count bytes with PHP (or it doesnt matter ? an rsa function would do that for me ?)

Comment: Check [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php) if you find some solution with PHP

Answer (score 0):

The public key is an base64-encoded DER-encoded SubjectPublicKey structure: see [RFC5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4) for details. There is a PHP method to do the bas64 decoding, and certainly something out there to decode the result. You can convert the key with openssl rsa into something that [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) can work with, for example.